# Samsung or Microsoft drivers?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

I have to re-install Windows 7 Home Premium on a laptop (Samsung RF710) where the install hasn't recognized some of the hardware.

I downloaded the LAN driver from Samsung in order to have the Ethernet port work so that I could do the updates.

It has dawned on me, should I download the drivers at Samsung or will the updates from Microsoft do the same thing?

I'll venture a guess that they are most likely the same thing.

**Edit #1**

Laptop is from 2010, manufacturer drivers are dated 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft is usually last to know of a driver set & often provide only minimum spec; get from the manufacturer

Comment: Good point. However, I don't have a new PC (from 2010) and the drivers are almost all dated 2011. What should I do in that case?

Comment: Install the ones from 2011 then update the non-Samsung ones, if the machine will let you - Graphics drivers particularly. Perhaps try [IOBit's Driver Booster](http://www.iobit.com/driver-booster.php) - watch out for any 'extras' it may try to install, but it's nagware only & won't insist on being paid for before it will actually function. None of these driver installers are ideal, but that one's not bad & certainly not 'evil' like some of them. Set a restore point first, just to be on the safe side, but I've never known it to break anything.